# How to set the reference to the 'leafletElement' using Typescript inside react-leaflet?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, leaflet, react-leaflet

The problem is that while using TS in my React project I need to set the type of the `useRef()` function, but I don't know what it is. So as in the code below I'm setting it to `any` and calling the `leafletElement` afterwards. The problem that occurs is that the element is always undefined even after the map is referenced through the `whenCreated` function isnide `MapContainer`.

I am trying to set the `MapContainer` in a way that it shows all the `Marker` making it dynamically resizable so when the location is changed it updates it and adjusts the `MapContainer` because it does not have a `ref` property.

[Example I'm trying to reproduce](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-call-fitbounds-and-getbounds-in-react-leaflet-1m50m?file=/src/Map.js:1228-1242)

```
const MapTry = () => {
const [nodes, setNodes] = useState<INode[]>([]);
const [devices, setDevices] = useState<IDevice[]>([]);

const [nodeDeviceTest, deviceNodeConnection] = useState([]);
var arrObj: any = [];
var arrOfBounds: any = [];
var mapRef = useRef<any>();
var groupRef = useRef<any>();


var device = new L.Icon({
    iconUrl: deviceCar,
    iconSize: [30, 30],
    iconAnchor: [16, 3],
    popupAnchor: [1, -1],
    shadowSize: [41, 41]
});

var deviceNode = new L.Icon({
    iconUrl: nodeDevice,
    iconSize: [20, 30],
    iconAnchor: [10, 0],
    popupAnchor: [1, -34],
    shadowSize: [41, 41],

})

useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
        const user = checkUserData();
        const project = checkProjectData();
        debugger;
        if (mapRef.current && mapRef) {
            let map = mapRef.current.leafletElement;
            let group = groupRef.current.leafletElement;
            map.fitBounds(group.getBounds());
        }



        const result = await getProjectNodeDeviceMap(project, user);
        console.log(result);
        if (result) {
            if (result.devicesToNodes) {
                for (var i = 0; i < result.devicesToNodes.length; i++) {
                    var objec = {
                        nodeId: "",
                        devId: "",
                        deviceLat: 0,
                        deviceLong: 0,
                        nodeLat: 0,
                        nodeLong: 0
                    }
                    for (var j = 0; j < result.devices.length; j++) {
                        if (result.devicesToNodes[i].deviceId == result.devices[j].deviceId) {
                            objec.deviceLat = result.devices[j].latitude
                            objec.deviceLong = result.devices[j].longitude
                            objec.devId = result.devices[j].deviceId
                            arrOfBounds.push([result.devices[j].latitude, result.devices[j].longitude])

                            for (var k = 0; k < result.nodes.length; k++) {
                                if (result.devicesToNodes[i].nodeId == result.nodes[k].id) {
                                    objec.nodeLat = result.nodes[k].latitude
                                    objec.nodeLong = result.nodes[k].longitude
                                    objec.nodeId = result.nodes[k].id
                                    arrOfBounds.push([result.nodes[k].latitude, result.nodes[k].longitude])


                                    arrObj.push(objec);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    deviceNodeConnection(arrObj);
                }
            }

            if (result.nodes) {
                result.nodes.map((node: INode) => {
                    if (node.state == "running") {
                        node.color = "success";
                    }

                    else if (node.state == "error") {
                        node.color = "danger";
                    }

                    else if (node.state == "stopped") {
                        node.color = "warning";
                    }

                    else {
                        node.color = "info";
                    }
                })
            }

            setNodes(result.nodes)
            setDevices(result.devices)
        }
    }

    const timer = setInterval(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, 3000)

    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
}, [arrObj])

return (
    <div className="col-md-9">
        <div className="card shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
            <div className="text-center">
                <h3>Showcase</h3>
            </div>
            {devices && devices.length > 0 && <MapContainer
                whenCreated={mapInstance => { mapRef.current = mapInstance }}
                center={[devices[0].latitude, devices[0].longitude]}
                zoom={6}
                scrollWheelZoom={true}
                minZoom={2}
                maxBoundsViscosity={1.0}
                zoomControl={false}
                style={{ backgroundColor: "inherit", width: "100%", height: "60vh" }}
            >
                <TileLayer
                    attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                />
                {nodeDeviceTest.length > 0 && nodeDeviceTest?.map((point: any) => {
                    return <Polyline key={point.deviceId} positions={[
                        [point.nodeLat, point.nodeLong], [point.deviceLat, point.deviceLong]
                    ]} color={'blue'} dashArray="5,10" />
                })}
                <FeatureGroup ref={groupRef}>
                    {nodes?.map((point: any) => (
                        <Marker
                            zIndexOffset={100}
                            icon={deviceNode}
                            key={point.Id}
                            position={[
                                point.latitude,
                                point.longitude
                            ]}
                        >
                            <Popup>
                                <br />
                                Node: {point.name}
                                <br />
                                State:
                                <span className={`text-${point.color}`}>
                                    <b>{point.state}</b>
                                </span>
                            </Popup>
                        </Marker>
                    ))}
                    {devices?.map((dev: any) => {
                        return <Marker
                            key={dev.deviceId}
                            position={[
                                dev.latitude,
                                dev.longitude
                            ]}
                            icon={device}
                        >
                            <Popup>
                                Device id: {dev.deviceId}
                            </Popup>
                        </Marker>
                    })}
                </FeatureGroup>
            </MapContainer>}
        </div>
    </div>

)}
```

Also i hope the `FeatureGroup` is properly referenced.Sorry if I missed something in my explanation. I am fairly new to React/TS.

EDIT: This is the example code I created

```
const Mapp = () => {
const devices = [{
    deviceId: "1-528a-4f80-9c7a-124108f86895",
    latitude: 45.5,
    longitude: 18.7
},
{
    deviceId: "2-528a-4f80-9c7a-124108f86895",
    latitude: 60.5,
    longitude: 18.7
}]

const nodes = [{
    id: "test-node-1",
    latitude: 45,
    longitude: 15.4566,
    name: "TestNode1",
    state: "running",
},
{
    id: "test-node-2",
    latitude: 47,
    longitude: 15.4566,
    name: "TestNode2",
    state: "running",
}]

const devicesToNodes = [{
    deviceId: "1-528a-4f80-9c7a-124108f86895",
    nodeId: "test-node-1"
},
{
    deviceId: "2-528a-4f80-9c7a-124108f86895",
    nodeId: "test-node-1"
}]

const arrOfLatLang = [{
    deviceLat: 45.5,
    deviceLong: 18.7,
    nodeLat: 47,
    nodeLong: 15.4566
},
{
    deviceLat: 60.5,
    deviceLong: 18.7,
    nodeLat: 47,
    nodeLong: 15.4566
}]


return (
    <MapContainer
        style={{ marginLeft: "200px" }}
        center={[devices[0].latitude, devices[0].longitude]}
        zoom={6}
        scrollWheelZoom={true}
        bounds={[[90, 180], [-90, 180]]}
        minZoom={2}
        maxBoundsViscosity={1.0}
    >
        <TileLayer
            attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        {arrOfLatLang.length > 0 && arrOfLatLang?.map((point: any) => {
            return <Polyline key={point.deviceId} positions={[
                [point.nodeLat, point.nodeLong], [point.deviceLat, point.deviceLong]
            ]} color={'blue'} dashArray="5,10" />
        })}

        {nodes?.map((point: any) => (
            <Marker
                zIndexOffset={100}
                key={point.Id}
                position={[
                    point.latitude,
                    point.longitude
                ]}
            >
                <Popup>
                    <br />
                    Node: {point.name}
                    <br />
                    State:
                    <span className={`text-${point.color}`}>
                        <b>{point.state}</b>
                    </span>
                </Popup>
            </Marker>
        ))}
        {devices?.map((dev: any) => {
            return <Marker
                key={dev.deviceId}
                position={[
                    dev.latitude,
                    dev.longitude
                ]}
            >
                <Popup>
                    Device id: {dev.deviceId}
                </Popup>
            </Marker>
        })}
    </MapContainer>
)}
```

Comment: It is not easy to go through the code you provide at the moment. It would be better to create a demo to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Sorry for that, I will try to post an example ASAP. Thank you.

Comment: @kboul I edited the post and added the example. I am not sure about the logic that is needed to work as the example I gave as a link, so I'm open to all options. In my case i am using function components and hooks with 'react-leaflet' (v3) and 'typescript'. Sorry fo the wait.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use the underlying leaflet instance type. For the map, its `L.Map`, for a featuregroup, its `L.FeatureGroup`:

```
var mapRef = useRef<L.Map>();
var groupRef = useRef<L.FeatureGroup>();
```

Note that setting the map ref in `whenCreated`, like you're doing with `whenCreated={mapInstance => { mapRef.current = mapInstance }}`, is not a great idea, and may cause problems with the way you're trying to type the refs.  I recommend using a proper ref prop on the MapContainer (`ref={mapRef}`), or setting the `mapRef` as a state variable instead, as described in the [example in the react-leaflet docs](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-external-state/).

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I will try to refactor the map referencing as you mentioned, but regarding the "setting the type" I am getting an error  ->"Property 'leafletElement' does not exist on type 'Map'.ts(2339)". The imports connected to leaflet I am using are "react-leaflet" and "leaflet".

Comment: Because for react-leaflet version 3, it doesn't.  Considering you are using a `MapContainer` and not a `Map`, I assume you're using react-leaflet version 3.  You no longer need to access `ref.current.leafletElement` to get the elemtent, its just `ref.current`